# Div is not changing its property

Tags: jquery, html, propertychanged

I have this HTML Code

```
<div id="dvtest">
    <input id="check1" type="checkbox" checked="checked">
    <label for="check1">Check me</label>
</div>
```

and in script section have this function

```
$(function () {
  $("#dvtest").children.prop({
        disabled: true
  });
});
```

why the "**div**" doesnt become Disabled??? (because , if its disabled, checkedBox should be disable as well.is it Correct?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to call the function

```
$("#dvtest").children().prop({
//                   ^ - the call
```

Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dv1q62ex/

Comment: thanks but I didnt catch what you mean? I want to disable it when all DOMS loaded. I did it like this code  <script>
$( "input[type='checkbox']" ).prop({
disabled: true
});
</script>  which is in JQuery website.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot disable a div, however as per your requirement you want to disable a checkbox inside the div #dvtest on certain scenario. So you can directly select the check box which already has an id and disable it,

```
$('#check1').attr('disabled', 'true');
```

The below code actually loops through all the children inside the div 
and tries to disable all the child tags. You can use it if you have multiple checkboxes within a div that you need to enable or disable.

```
$(function () {
  $("#dvtest").children().prop({
    disabled: true
 });
});
```

This code also tries to disable the label tag which is present inside #dvtest, however disabled property not supported by label tag and nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as:

```
$(function () {
 $("#dvtest").children().prop({
    disabled: true
 });
});
```

Comment: I exactly did that in my code. it is anything wrong with that?

Comment: @SarahN I just posted and didn't look up. Sometimes there might be similar answers closely as this solutions needs only one change.